# Does the Flink Kubernetes Operator support the deployment of Apache Flink Stateful Functions?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

The attempt to deploy Apache Flink Stateful Functions using the Kubernetes operator did not succeed. Does the Kubernetes operator provide support for such deployments?

https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator

**tried the deployment:**

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: statefun
spec:
  image: flink-statefun-local:3.3.0-java11
  flinkVersion: v1_16
  flinkConfiguration:
    statefun.flink-job-name: Statefun Application
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "1"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2024m"
      cpu: 2
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/flink
              name: jar
      volumes:
        - name: jar
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp/flink
            type: Directory
  job:
    jarURI: local:///tmp/flink/flink-statefun-uber-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    parallelism: 1
    upgradeMode: stateless
```

When attempting to use the 'flink:17' image, I encountered an issue.
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An extension with type TypeName(io.statefun.kafka.v1, ingress) does not exist.`

But k8s operator works perfectly for Apache Flink streaming applications.

*module.yaml* has been used

```
kind: io.statefun.endpoints.v2/http
spec:
  functions: ua.execution/*
  urlPathTemplate: http://localhost:8080/v1/functions
  transport:
    type: io.statefun.transports.v1/async
    timeouts:
      call: 5min
      connect: 20sec
      read: 10sec
      write: 10sec
---
kind: io.statefun.kafka.v1/ingress
spec:
  id: engine/rules-updated-event
  address: localhost:9092
  consumerGroupId: test-dev
  startupPosition:
    type: latest
  topics:
    - topic: topictest
      valueType: ua.store.model/UpdatedResponse
      targets:
        - ua.execution/finUpdatedIngressStore
```

Comment: Statefun isn't supported by the Kubernetes Operator

Comment: Hey @MartijnVisser, it appears we've started Statefun by the operator. Currently in the testing phase."

Comment: That's possible, but it isn't supported